# How do I clone something to the coordinates of a player? 1.12.2

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am making a map in 1.12.2, I want to make it so when you trow a specific item on the ground there will be a pillar placed on those coordinates. Can someone help me? (I already have the dropping system, I only need the pillar to be teleported)

Answer (score 1):

It's very similar to the 1.13+ variant, just with different syntax:

```
/execute @e[type=item,<whatever other conditions>] ~ ~ ~ clone <lower pillar coordinates> <higher pillar coordinates>  ~ ~ ~
```

Replace `<whatever other coordinates>` with the conditions that you have already figured out (scoreboard or whatever), `<lower pillar coordinates>` with the lowest X, Y and Z coordinates of the pre-built structure (for example `123 456 789`) and `<higher pillar coordinates>` with the highest ones (for example `133 466 799` for an 11×11×11 pillar).

Comment: You should also check for OnGround, as without it the pillar will spawn on your head the instant you drop the item.

Comment: The asker said that they had already figured that out. And it's a separate problem from the cloning part (especially in 1.12, where you need `/scoreboard`).